# Why isn't magit-version available?

Tags: magit, autoload

I have Git 2.5.3 installed and am using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 on Ubuntu. I just [installed Magit from MELPA](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Installing-from-an-Elpa-archive.html):

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-install 'magit)
```

If I then try to use `M-x magit-version RET` to try to make sure it installed properly, Emacs helpfully tells me

```
M-x magit-version [No match]
```

But if I just type `M-x magit- RET`, I'm presented with a long list of Magit operations like `magit-commit`, `magit-diff`, etc. Everything seems to be all there except `magit-version`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `magit-version` is not autoloaded in `magit.el`. If you look at the source, you will notice that that function definition is not preceded by `;;;###autoload` *(as of Magit version 20150921.1712)*.

If you eval `magit.el` file, you will see that `M-x magit-version` would then be available.

### How to get `M-x magit-version` working?

There are a couple of ways to do that:

- Try doing `M-x magit-version` only after the `magit` package gets loaded. For instance, you can do that after you launch a common magit command like `M-x magit-status`.
- You can add the below snippet to your emacs config if you use `M-x magit-version` quite frequently before using any other magit command.

  ```el
  (autoload #'magit-version "magit" nil t)
  ```
- If you use `use-package`, you can add `magit-version` to the [list of commands after the `:commands` key](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#the-basics) of `(use-package magit ..)` instead of the above `autoload` statement (*as `use-package` does the same thing under the hood*).
- Or you can open an issue on `magit` github asking the developer if he sees fit autoloading this function.

---

Check out the [**Autoload**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) chapter in Elisp Manual to learn more about autoloading.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Judging from [this page](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Post_002dinstallation-tasks.html), I assumed that `magit-version` was usable outside of any context, but I guess I was mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: That's a good argument for autoloading. I've done so now.