# projectile-switch-project not working with autoload

Tags: projectile, autoload

When I attempt to autoload projectile like so

`(autoload 'projectile-global-mode "projectile" " t nil)`

And then open Emacs I cannot use `projectile-switch-project` (Symbol's function definition is void: projectile-switch-project). However once entering a project and calling one of the other projectile commands I can then call `projectile-switch-project` without any problems. From what I can gather from the error message and the behavior of the problem, it seems to me as if `projectile-switch-project` isn't autoloaded. This error doesn't occur with any of the commands which further confirms my suspicions.

In saying this I am no elisp expert so I would like to see if any of you have experienced this problem and found a way to solve this.

Comment: You can always just load the whole file and not mess with autoload. If this occurs with an empty .emacs, you should file a bug report.

Comment: @Qudit yeah, I guess. I just found it weird that every other projectile command would be autoloaded but switch-project not.

Comment: Hence, my suggestion for a bug report...

Comment: Ok I shall do so. (I didn't see your edit there)

Comment: @intricatedetail Here's a very related solution to an earlier question on emacs.stackexahnge: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16881/115. The only difference is that it's about autoloading a different function in a different package. But the solution to how to autoload stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To autoload the interactive command `projectile-switch-project`, use something like:

```el
(autoload #'projectile-switch-project "projectile" nil :interactive)
```

the fourth arg INTERACTIVE should be non-nil since you need to call `projectile-switch-project` from <kbd>M-x</kbd> (interactively).